# Defining scope for lazy loading (hibernate)

Tags: hibernate, loading, lazy-evaluation

For lazy loading, hibernate makes proxies. For lazy=true (that is also the default), I want my data access layer and business layer to use this feature. But once the loaded data is send to the presentation layer, i want "Null pointer exception" instead of "LazyInitializationException could not initialize proxy - no Session" if some property is accessed for the DTO/BO that is not initialized.
Conceptually, I dont want to define lazy=false in my individual mappings. Is theres some solution which I want or any good alternative approach?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll create a much more stable application if you chase down your LazyInitializationExceptions through the development and testing process and figure out the correct graph hydration, rather than trying to mask it with this sort of scheme.

This said, since you want to maintain the normal behavior in your lower layers, your best bet is going to be catching any LazyInitializationExceptions at the business layer and throwing the NullPointerException to the presentation layer.

One option might be to look into servlet filters and hooking them into the relevant level of the processing chain.